# How to generate swagger code gen for a spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-codegen

I need help in getting clarification for below mentioned points

1. I have a swagger json. From this I want to generate Model separately by passing java as language. api and invoker clsses by passing spring as language and want to add model jar as dependency.  Because I want to use model for different projects commonly. So I want to include a build task to generate model jar every time to get latest models from json. and will issue swagger code gen command with spring as language while trying to create project. Is this correct way of handling. If not can someone let me know best of handling this.
2. How to handle versioning from swagger.

I am new in using swagger and spring. Please suggest me best to go

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar.  I have my models in a separate project which is then a dependency for a bunch of API projects.  This is because the APIs sometimes call each other, so need to know about each others objects.

What I do is:

- Swagger structure:

  - In the models project I have a swagger containing just the definitions (empty object as paths)
  - In the API projects I have a swagger which references the definitions in the models project
- Build process

  - Build the models project first with `generateApis = false`
  - Build the APIs with typeMappings and ImportMappings in the config, telling them to take all the models in common from that namespace

I use the maven plugin to run the codegen.  I have a pretty hacky bash script that updates the type mappings in the pom when I have added new objects to the models